# PrintWriter class not working as expected

Tags: java, printing, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, file-writing

I have a program that stores information into a binary tree.

I am attempting to print all of the information on to a text file using `PrintWriter`, which has worked for me in previous situations, but I've had no luck this time.

It is mandatory to have the information called in the node via an object. I have debugged and determined the placement of the nodes in the tree is working perfectly, so the problem is with printing to a file.

The last thing to note is that if I print to the console via `System.out`, it prints perfectly.

```
import java.io.*;

public class GALABST
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Tree directory = new Tree();

        InputData newPerson1 = new InputData("luca", "galati", "asdasda", "sadfasdf");
        directory.insert(newPerson1);
        InputData newPerson2 = new InputData("sdfasf", "blackman", "asdasda", "sadfasdf");
        directory.insert(newPerson2);
        InputData newPerson3 = new InputData("fsdgdfg", "kramer", "asdasda", "sadfasdf"); 
        directory.insert(newPerson3);
        InputData newPerson4 = new InputData("dsafgas", "wallace", "asdasda", "sadfasdf");
        directory.insert(newPerson4);
        InputData newPerson5 = new InputData("asdfasdfasdf", "dangelo", "asdasda", 
        "sadfasdf");
        directory.insert(newPerson5);
        InputData newPerson6 = new InputData("sfasdasfas", "alla", "asdasda", "sadfasdf");
        directory.insert(newPerson6);
        InputData newPerson7 = new InputData("hfdhsds", "eeves", "asdasda", "sadfasdf");
        directory.insert(newPerson7);

        File outputFile = new File ("Contacts.txt");
        outputFile.delete();
        directory.print();
    }
}

class InputData
{
    String firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber;

    InputData (String fN, String lN, String a, String pN)
    {
        firstName = fN;
        lastName = lN;
        address = a;
        phoneNumber = pN;
    }
}

class Tree
{
    private Node root;

    class Node
    {
        InputData inputData;
        Node leftChild, rightChild;

        Node(InputData iD)
        {
            inputData = iD;
            this.leftChild = null;
            this.rightChild = null;
        }
    }

    void insert(InputData inputData)
    {
        root = insert(root, inputData);
    }

    Node insert(Node root, InputData inputData)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node(inputData);
            return root;
        }
        if (root.inputData.lastName.compareTo(inputData.lastName) < 0)
        {
            root.rightChild = insert(root.rightChild, inputData);
        }
        else if (root.inputData.lastName.compareTo(inputData.lastName) > 0)
        {
            root.leftChild = insert(root.leftChild, inputData);
        }
        else
        {
            if (root.inputData.firstName.compareTo(inputData.firstName) < 0)
            {
                root.rightChild = insert(root.rightChild, inputData);
            }
            else if (root.inputData.firstName.compareTo(inputData.firstName) > 0)
            {
                root.leftChild = insert(root.leftChild, inputData);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Info already present in contacts");
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    public void print() throws IOException
    {
        print(root);
    }

    private void print(Node root) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Contacts.txt"), true);

        if(root != null)
        {
            print(root.leftChild);
            writer.write(root.inputData.firstName + "  " + root.inputData.lastName + "  " + 
            root.inputData.address + "  " + root.inputData.phoneNumber);
            print(root.rightChild);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Anyone who can help, I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `print` method is the creation of a new `PrintWriter` instance for every call writing the first line of the file, so at the closing of every `PrintWriter` instance it overwrites the first line of the file. A method to avoid this behaviour is creating one `PrintWriter` and pass it as a parameter like below:

```
public void print() throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Contacts.txt"), true);
    print(root, writer);
    writer.close();
}

private void print(Node root, PrintWriter writer) throws IOException
{
    if(root != null)
    {
        print(root.leftChild, writer);
        writer.write(root.inputData.firstName + "  " + root.inputData.lastName + "  " + 
        root.inputData.address + "  " + root.inputData.phoneNumber + "\n"); <-- added \n for clarity
        print(root.rightChild, writer);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me what you are trying to do. As darioscity has pointed, the main problem is that you are creating a new instance of PrintWriter each time; hence overwriting.
You can see that you are actually writing something: the fist Node  (bc it is the last one you are writing, hence this particular one is not overwritten) of you tree is in the file. Until reaching that one, you have been writing some other stuff (the other Nodes) and overwriting it each time.

```
public void print() throws IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Contacts.txt"), true);

    print(root, writer);
}

private void print(Node root, PrintWriter file) throws IOException {

    if (root != null) {
        file.write(root.inputData.firstName + "  " + root.inputData.lastName + "  "
                + root.inputData.address + "  " + root.inputData.phoneNumber + "\n");
        print(root.leftChild, file);

        print(root.rightChild, file);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

}

Note that with that code (idk if this is what you want) you are not writing every node.

Comment: I said *it is not clear ..* bc I don't know if you want to print every node or you dont

Comment: Why do you delete the file right after you create it? Also, don't close the file in the Node.print(Node) method. You should keep the one Writer around and pass it as a parameter. Once you close the writer, that closes the file.